# Anacrontab not running scheduled bash scripts after computer startup

Tags: bash, shell, cron

I have scheduled a job to run after my computer starts up. The job isn't running for some reason, but, after inspecting /var/spool/anacron/ the log file is printing (showing a date) that it has ran.

My AWS S3 bucket is still empty.

Here is my anacrontab under etc/. Please note that I tried removing "source" from the code snippet below, and it still wouldn't work.

```
# These replace cron's entries
1   5   cron.daily  run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily
7   10  cron.weekly run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly
@daily  10  codeBackup  source /home/tzadiko/Code/AWS/backupCode.sh
```

Here is my backupCode.sh. I have purposely blurred my bucket's name.

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/aws s3 sync /home/tzadiko/Code/C++ s3://*********
```

I do not receive any error message.

Comment: check if the script is executable

Comment: @LinPy it is.    ```File: backupCode.sh
  Size: 79         Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 10302h/66306d Inode: 27397764    Links: 1
Access: (0755/-rwxr-xr-x)  Uid: ( 1000/ tzadiko)   Gid: ( 1000/ tzadiko)
Access: 2019-09-13 15:49:00.091912006 -0400
Modify: 2019-09-12 13:01:48.777436634 -0400
Change: 2019-09-14 08:57:10.863509163 -0400
 Birth: -```